# Set rows in Python 2D array to another row without Numpy?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I want to "set" the values of a row of a Python nested list to another row without using NumPy.

I have a sample list:

```
lst = [[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [5, 2, 3]]
```

I want to make row 1 to row 2, row 2 to row 3, and row 3 to row 1. My desired output is:

```
lst = [[0, 2, 3],
       [5, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 1]]
```

How can I do this **without** using Numpy?

I tried to do something like `arr[[0, 1]] = arr[[1, 0]]` but it gives the error `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: are you trying to set the whole row, or a single element? A single element of a list of lists is accessed via `my_list[outer_index][inner_index]`

Comment: Those are lists, not arrays. The distinction is important in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very straightforward way:

```
arr = [arr[-1], *arr[:-1]]
```

Or another way to achieve the same:

```
arr = [arr[-1]] + arr[:-1]
```

`arr[-1]` is the last element of the array. And `arr[:-1]` is everything up to the last element of the array.

The first solution builds a new list and adds the last element first and then all the other elements. The second one constructs a list with only the last element and then extends it with the list containing the rest.

Note: naming your list an array doesn't make it one. Although you can access a list of lists like `arr[i1][i2]`, it's still just a list of lists. Look at [the `array` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) for Python's actual array.

The solution user @MadPhysicist provided comes down to the second solution provided here, since `[arr[-1]] == arr[-1:]`

Answer (score 1):

Since python does not actually support multidimensional lists, your task becomes simpler by virtue of the fact that you are dealing with a list containing lists of rows.

To roll the list, just reassemble the outer container:

```
result = lst[-1:] + lst[:-1]
```

Numpy has a special interpretation for lists of integers, like `[0, 1]`, tuples, like `:, -1`, single integers, and slices. Python lists only understand single integers and slices as indices, and do not accept tuples as multidimensional indices, because, again, lists are fundamentally one-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

use this generalisation

```
arr = [arr[-1]] + arr[:-1]
```

which according to your example means

```
arr[0],arr[1],arr[2] = arr[1],arr[2],arr[0]
```

or

```
arr = [arr[2]]+arr[:2]
```

or

```
arr = [arr[2]]+arr[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
>>> lst = [[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [5, 2, 3]]
>>> lst = [*lst[1:], *lst[:1]]
>>>lst
 [[0, 2, 3],
   [5, 2, 3],
   [0, 0, 1]]
```